# My Visual Studio is not letting me start my program

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I keep clicking on start program and due to my anti virus software(AVG), it says something along the terms of it having a chance to be a harm to my computer. and it then says its all fine and the system will start up soon, but it doesn't, nothing happens at all. I'm very new to Visual Studio, can someone explain it to me please

Comment: Please provide sufficient context for us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly. The blue bar at the bottom turns orange, the toolbox closes up, and in the orange bar it flashes loading simbols for accessablility.illbl (or something like that, and it flashes really fast. And for others computers the form they were working on actually popped out and they could use the bottons they made. I dont know why mine doesnt do that. I feel like i haven't configured something right yet. @AndrewFan

Comment: I think you've said your problem in the question: you're using an antivirus. Try disabling it, it doesn't seem to be anything to do with VS.

Comment: @Alejandro I tried that, but I'm still not getting any results